# Download OSM data from XYZ Tile

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, download

In QGIS 2.18 it was possible to download vector data from OpenStreetMap by going into Vector>OpenStreetMap>Download Data. How can we go about this in QGIS 3.0?

Comment: For the moment, you have to wait for the QuickOSM plugin to be updated, or use the Overpass turbo website.

Comment: as a workaround you'll can try the already to shapefile processed and ready to download OSM data extracts from the geofabrik (daily updated): http://download.geofabrik.de/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickOSM plugin has been released in QGIS 3. It's available in your plugin manager. Then you can find it in the vector menu.
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/